# What is the best practise to autostart unprivileged lxc containers on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: ubuntu, best-practices, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

The current implementation of the LXC technology [deals nicely with an issue of starting the *privileged* containers upon system start.](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/21/lxc-1-0-your-second-container/). Users of the unprivileged containers (which arguably promise better security) don't get any working out-of-the-box solution for autostarting their containers.

I know of two ways of achieving this goal. I need to decide which one to take (or maybe there is another?)

Both methods require that the `lxc.start.auto 1` be set in [the configuration file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html).

### Transforming an existing privileged container

In short [one must grant range of subuids to root and `chmod o+x` permission to `/var/lib/lxc`](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2014-May/006834.html).

### Invoking unprivileged container via a custom upstart job

The `lxc-autostart` command invoked by the owner of the unprivileged containers (without the `sudo`) starts all the unprivileged auto-start containers. The problem is only with how to run it during system startup.

This is tough, because any form of `sudo -u <lxc-user> -- lxc-autostart` nor `su -l <lxc-user> -c lxc-autostart` wouldn't work - I guess they don't handle ranges of `subuid` well. The only way to get root autostarting user's containers is through ridiculously complex `ssh <lxc-user>@localhost lxc-autostart`.  <s>I haven't tried the `setgid` and `setuid` stanzas yet (something tells me, it wouldn't work either).</s>  EDIT: My intuition was right. Setting the `setgid` and `setuid` in upstart script doesn't help either.

Comment: I was using the `uidmapshift` approach outlined under your first heading. It worked fine.

Comment: I found what's different if you use `su`/`sudo` instead of ssh: check the file `/proc/self/cgroup`. The reason must be somewhere around PAM, namely libpam-systemd. I wrote something about this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/623789/problem-setting-up-a-user-space-lxc-container